# ip forwarding enabled at every boot

Tags: networking, security

Recently I noticed that `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` returns 1, something that is not recommended and I generally do not enable things I do not need that increase my attack vector.

I thought, okay simply set `net.ipv4.ip_forward=0` in `/etc/sysctl.conf`. After a reboot it still returned 1. Strange I thought, grepped the whole `/etc` directory for "net.ipv4.ip_forward" and found that ufw had it in the config file too, but commented. To be safe I also inserted `net.ipv4.ip_forward=0` there. After a reboot ip forwarding was still enabled.
Temporary disabling works, by echoing zero to the proc file.

How could I trace which process changes that on boot?

Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug which causes sysctl values to be loaded before the network is properly initialized. This causes network settings in `/etc/sysctl.conf` to be ignored. A solution to this may be to `/etc/init.d/procps restart` to `/etc/local.rc`, so the initialization is repeated.

The bug in question: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/procps/+bug/50093

Answer (score 0):

To enable the changes made in `sysctl.conf` you will need to run the command:

`sudo sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf`

**Reference**

1. [How to Enable IP Forwarding in Linux](http://www.ducea.com/2006/08/01/how-to-enable-ip-forwarding-in-linux/)

Comment: From what I understand that loads the options at runtime, which works. At the next boot however I am still in the same situation.

Comment: Really weird that it doesn't change for you. After you reboot, does it still say `net.ipv4.ip_forward=0` in `sysctl.conf`? Or does it change to 1 again?

Comment: The config file remains untouched, it's just ignored, at least it seems. `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` says 1. So I guess some process changes that ...

Comment: What's your output from `sudo sysctl -a --pattern forward`?

Comment: Output: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10111500/

Answer (score -1):

If you need to enable it in script you can use commands below to enable

```
sed -i 's/#net.ipv4.ip_forward=1/net.ipv4.ip_forward=1/' /etc/sysctl.conf
sysctl -p
```

or disable:

```
sed -i 's/net.ipv4.ip_forward=1/net.ipv4.ip_forward=0/' /etc/sysctl.conf
sysctl -p
```

Comment: The OP has explicitly said that they already tried editing this file yet it did not work.